# why browser needs java plug in?

Tags: java, browser, applet

I am a seasoned java developer I feel I am  quite good in java programming. Unfortunately I could not make why we need java plug in for browser. I know it is not mandatory to have this plug in.

My findings. 
[here](http://lifehacker.com/5988800/what-is-java-is-it-insecure-and-should-i-use-it) It is advised to disable java plugin.

Question ?

 why we need java plug in  browsers. I know applet runs in browser apart form applet what are the  use cases of java plug in ?

Clarification:
I am not using the applet. I am interested in other use cases of java plug in browser.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comment I think no where I mentioned I am using applet

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. You state that you know it isn't mandatory: therefore you don't 'need' one at all. You can *use* one, to run Java code: applets or JWS applications.

Comment: Ok. Thanks the answer I was looking was 'JWS applications' thanks. I will explore on that will post if I find worth of share.

Answer (score 0):

Java web start 
Reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/

> Java Web Start is an application-deployment technology that gives you
>   the power to launch full-featured applications with a single click
>   from your Web browser. You can now download and launch applications,
>   such as a complete spreadsheet program or an Internet chat client,
>   without going through complicated installation procedures.

Hope that helps some one.